# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean

Tags: php, oracle

Hola por qué me sale ese error ? esta funcion es para validar si existe un usuario o no pero me sale este problema:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn()
>   on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php:50 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\registro.php(38):
>   usuarioExiste('ortega') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php on line 50

function usuarioExiste($usuario)
        {
            global $db;

```
        $num = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=". $usuario)->fetchColumn(); //<<<<<<< AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA

        printf("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('LO DEVUELTO ES : $num'); </script>"); 

        if ($num != 0)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

podria usar rowCount pero como es un select este en ORACLE no funciona bien, solo con update, insert o detele. De que otra forma puedo saber el numero de filas afectadas de la ultima consulta select que hice en PDO ORACLE ?
o como puedo solucionar ese error del codigo.
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene dos problemas:

1. Es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Para corregirlo debes implementar consultas preparadas.
2. No estás usando bien `fetchColumn`.

Aparte de esto, usaremos otras técnicas, como los [operadores ternarios](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php), para simplificar el código.

Ya que lo mencionas en la pregunta, `rowCount` no lo necesitas aquí, pues lo que hace tu consulta es precisamente contar las filas que hay.

Propongo esta solución:

```
    $bolResultado=false;                        
    $strSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=:id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($strSQL);
    if ($stmt){
        /*Pasamos los datos aparte para evitar la Inyección de código malicioso*/
        $arrParams=array(":id"=>$usuario);
        $stmt->execute($arrParams);
        $num=$stmt->fetchColumn();
        /*El operador ternario permitirá hacer la evaluación una sola vez*/
        $bolResultado=($num != 0);
        printf("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('LO DEVUELTO ES : $num'); </script>");         
    return $bolResultado;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la consulta no retorna ningún resultadom como un INSERT o tiene algún error creo que devuelve true o false.

podrias validarlo asi:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=". $usuario);
if (!is_bool($query)){
   $num = $query->fetchColumn();
} else ...
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, pero si yo necesito retornar true o false dependiendo del valor que se genera en count entonces ahora dentro del if Padre debo poner otro if y else que retorne TRUE o F dependiendo del valor de $num ? me compliqué un poco, Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si dentro del if (!is_bool($query)) {.. deberias agregar tus validaciones